# Shuffling with seed does not give same result

Tags: python, numpy, shuffle, random-seed

Hi I have a problem with the use of the shuffle function of numpy. I've written the following code:

```
import numpy as np
rs = 43
np.random.seed(rs)
for i in range(1, 5):
    l = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    np.random.shuffle(l)
    print(l)
```

which gives me the following output:

```
[4, 3, 2, 1, 5]
[4, 5, 2, 1, 3]
[2, 1, 5, 3, 4]
[5, 2, 3, 4, 1]
```

Now if I set the seed shouldn't every shuffle give me the same result? I can't find my mistake please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Every time you run the program you should get the same results, not every time you call `shuffle`.

Answer (score 3):

If you put np.random.seed(rs) before the shuffle line inside the loop, you will get the same results for every iteration. Because you put it before the iterations your program will always produce the same different sequences every time you start the program. The reason why you get different results per iteration is because every time you call the shuffle function, the seed changes, thus you have different randoms per iteration!